# Is there a closed-form expression for these integrals?

Tags: integration

I am computing the following integrals by numerical integration and this takes a lot of time, although I'm sure there is a general closed-form formula but I can't find it.

Let $t$ be a vector of $\mathbb R_{+}^{d}$. For any integer $d \ge 1$, define $K_d$ as a convex subset of $\mathbb R^{d}$ by :

$$x \in K_d \iff \forall\, j \in {1,..,d}, \;x_j \ge 0 \text{ and }\sum\limits_{j=1}^d t_j x_j \le 1$$

I think $K_d$ is usually called a simplex, but I am not sure.

Let now $i$ be a vector of **integers** in $\mathbb{N}^{d}$, and consider the integral :

$$I_{i}^{d} = \int\limits_{K_{d}} \;\;\prod_{j=1}^{d} x_j^{i_j} \;\;\partial x_1,...,\partial x_d$$

Can we compute an expression for $I_{i}^{d}$? Maybe some recursion on $d$ or on $i$ can be found?

Edit:

I founded a paper that solves the problem, [Lasserre - Simple formula for integration of polynomials on a simplex](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.06736). it gives a formula a little more general, that reduces to the following :

$$\text{If and only if t_j = 1 for all j, }I_{i}^{d} = \frac{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{d} i_j}{(d+\lvert i \lvert)!}$$

Then, as a comment showed, generalisation can be done via

$$I_i^d(t) = \bigl(\prod_{j = 1}^d t_j^{-(i_j + 1)}\bigr)I_i^d(1)$$

Comment: I think that we have $I_i^d = \int_0^{1/t_d} x_d^{i_d}(1 - t_d x_d)^{\sum_{j = 1}^{d - 1} i_j}I_i^{d - 1}\mathrm dx_d$, but, if not that, then something very like it.

Comment: Nevermind, there is a formula there for exactly that : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.06736.pdf

Thanks anyway !

Comment: Glad you found it.  You might consider posting it as an answer, if it totally addresses your question.  \\ [Your](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371927/is-there-a-closed-form-expression-for-these-integrals#comment940579_371927) arXiv link, de-PDFd (and with the pun in its title unfurled for us to appreciate):  [Lasserre - Simple formula for integration of polynomials on a simplex](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.06736).

Comment: Actualy i'm still stuck on the change of variables... I'll Edit, and maybe you could help ?

Comment: If [my formula](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371927/is-there-a-closed-form-expression-for-these-integrals#comment940576_371927) is correct (but it's just off the top of my head, so you should doubt it), then it gives the recurrence $I_i^d = c_d I_i^{d - 1}$ with coefficient $c_d = \int_0^{1/t_d} x_d^{i_d}(1 - t_d x_d)^{\sum_{j = 1}^{d - 1} i_j}\mathrm dx_d$, so you'd just have to compute that integral.  If I'm right, I think you won't be able to avoid some such computation.

Comment: Note that, if $t_d$ is $1$, then [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371927/is-there-a-closed-form-expression-for-these-integrals#comment940794_371927) becomes $c_d = B(i_d + 1, \sum_{j = 1}^{d - 1} i_j + 1) = \dfrac{i_d!(\sum_{j = 1}^{d - 1} i_j)!}{(\sum_{j = 1}^d i_j)!}$, and that doesn't seem to simplify to your formula, so probably I made a mistake.  Anyway it seems that in general $c_d(t_d) = t_d^{-(i_d + 1)}c_d(1)$.

Comment: Your last proposition, $c_d(t_d) = t_{d}^{-(i_d+1}} c_d(1)$ is indeed wht i tried already, but my computer says that it's not right (compared to the brutal integration)

Comment: Edit: You ere right, i checked with wolframalpha and it seems that the integrator i was using is not that good... a lot of time wasted beacuase of a stupid piece of code that does not do what it seems to do. Thanks anyway ! I'll add the info to the main post

Comment: I think your last line should be $I_i^d(t) = \bigl(\prod_{j = 1}^d t_j^{-(i_j + 1)}\bigr)I_i^d(1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\Sigma_t=\{x_i \geq 0: x_1+\cdots +x_d=t\}$and $d\sigma_t$ is its surface measure, then $I_t=\int_{\Sigma_t}\prod_{i=1}^d x_i^{\alpha_i}\, d\sigma_t=t^{|\alpha|+d-1}I_1$ (change variable $x_i=ty_i$). Then for $\alpha_i>-1$
$$
\prod_{i=1}^d \Gamma (\alpha_i+1)=\int_{[0,\infty[^d} \prod_{i=1}^d x_i^{\alpha_i} e^{-(x_1+\cdots +x_d)}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt n} I_tdt=I_1\int_0^\infty t^{|\alpha|+d-1}\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt n} dt.
$$
This gives $I_1=\frac{\sqrt{n} \prod_{i=1}^d \Gamma (\alpha_i+1)}{\Gamma (|\alpha|+d)}$ and $$\int_{\{x_i \geq 0, x_1+\cdots +x_d \leq 1\}} \prod_{i=1}^d x_i^{\alpha_i}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt n}I_t=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^d \Gamma (\alpha_i+1)}{\Gamma (|\alpha|+d+1)}.$$